# How can I post a question with sample output?

Tags: support, formatting

I'm trying to show a code block with sample output to clarify my question. I know how to add a code block (indenting with 4 space) but I can't figure out how to show the output.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'item_id':[1,2,1,1,2], 
                'shop_id':['S1', 'S1', 'S1', 'S2', 'S2'], 
                'price':[10, 20, 10, 12, 18]})
df
```

In a Jupyter notebook, the above will print the dataframe and I have seen other posts displaying results. How can do it?

**Attempts:**

1. I have gone through [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/295700/easy-way-to-post-my-jupyter-notebook-output-in-a-stack-overflow-post) post which suggests that I can copy and paste the output from Jupyter but that didn't work.
2. I have tried to save my notebook as **HTML** and then insert the html snippet here. I thought when I run it it would display the output but it shows the entire html code instead.
3. Take a screenshot of my notebook and insert a link to it here. But I don't think this is the proper way to ask a question.

Please see example of what I wanted to post:

[image: Several sets of inputs and outputs where the input is a code block and the output is tabular data.]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Open a terminal or command-line window, start the ipython interpreter, and run the same commands that you ran in your example. This will give you the following pretty formatted output which you can copy/paste as plain text.

To format a block of text as code, select the block of code to be formatted with the mouse and click the pair of curly brackets **{}** in the Stack Overflow markdown editor to format the selected text as a code block or surround with groups of three backticks. Each group of backticks should be positioned on a separate line as shown in this example.

````
```
Markdown and HTML are turned off in code blocks 
```
````

To highlight a block of text as Python code, precede the block of Python code with the following HTML comment followed by a blank space: `<!-- language: python -->`

```python
$ ipython
Python 2.7.15rc1  
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 5.5.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.

In [1]: import pandas as pd
   ...: df1 = pd.DataFrame({'item_id':[1,2,1,1,2], 
   ...:                 'shop_id':['S1', 'S1', 'S1', 'S2', 'S2'], 
   ...:                 'price':[10, 20, 10, 12, 18]})
   ...: df1
   ...: 
Out[1]: 
   item_id  price shop_id
0        1     10      S1
1        2     20      S1
2        1     10      S1
3        1     12      S2
4        2     18      S2

In [2]: df2 = pd.DataFrame({'shop_id':['S1', 'S2'],
   ...:                     'shop_name':['shop1', 'shop2']})  
   ...: df2
   ...: 
Out[2]: 
  shop_id shop_name
0      S1     shop1
1      S2     shop2

In [3]: shop_map = {shop_id:shop_name for shop_id,shop_name in zip(df2.shop_id, 
   ...: df2.shop_name)}
   ...: shop_map
   ...: 
Out[3]: {'S1': 'shop1', 'S2': 'shop2'}

In [4]: df1['shop_name'] = df1['shop_id'].apply(lambda shop_id: shop_map[shop_id
   ...: ])
   ...: df1
   ...: 
Out[4]: 
   item_id  price shop_id shop_name
0        1     10      S1     shop1
1        2     20      S1     shop1
2        1     10      S1     shop1
3        1     12      S2     shop2
4        2     18      S2     shop2

In [5]:
```